# perf can find symbol in the kernel ,but can not find symbol in my program. How to fix it?

Tags: linux, performance, perf

you may have read this question:
[how can i get perf to find symbols in my program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933408/how-can-i-get-perf-to-find-symbols-in-my-program)

1)my question is:

when I use perf report , it gives a result like this:

```
    # Overhead  Command      Shared Object                    Symbol
    #   .  .  
    #
        99.59%     test  test               [.] 0x000003d4          
         0.21%     test  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] __do_fault          
         0.10%     test  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] run_timer_softirq   
         0.10%     test  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] __update_cpu_load   
         0.01%     test  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] set_task_comm       
         0.00%     test  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] intel_pmu_enable_all
```

That is: **the perf can find symbol in kernel but cannot find symbol in my program.**

my program is here:

```
     void longa() 
      { 
         int i,j; 
         for(i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) 
        j=i; //am I silly or crazy? I feel boring and desperate. 
      } 


     void foo2() 
     { 
       int i; 
       for(i=0 ; i < 10; i++) 
        longa(); 
     } 

     void foo1() 
     { 
       int i; 
       for(i = 0; i< 100; i++) 
          longa(); 
     } 

    int main(void) 
     { 
       foo1(); 
       foo2(); 
     }
```

2)I have compile the program like:

gcc test.c -g -o test

My env: **os:ubuntu kernel:3.10.9**

Comment: Did you solve this? I have had a similar problem and it was that somehow it wasnt cleaning up obj files properly.

Comment: I haven't solve this problem. Do you mean that "it works after you clean up your obj files"?  There was not obj files of mine,just elf and c files.

Comment: I have solved this question. you can see the solution below by yzark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Today, when I run `perf test`, I got a message saying `vmlinux symtab matches kallsyms: Failed`.

When I was looking for the reason, I found that the reason is that the value of `/proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict` is 1. When we set it to `0`, we will get the symbol in our program.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 possible sources of the problem:

- Your *perf* tool was compiled without [elfutils](https://fedorahosted.org/elfutils/) support.
- Your *perf* tool cannot find *libelf.so* library on your target.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem, and found out the reason is that the **dwarf** feature of my **perf** was not turned on.

A simple solution is to recompile **perf**:

```
% sudo apt-get install libdw-dev
% cd /path/to/perf/source/
% sudo make
% sudo make install
```

This enables **perf** to find all symbols!

If it still do not work for you, please refer to this link,
[how to compile a Linux perf tool with all features](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-compile-a-Linux-perf-tool-with-all-features-For-Linux-4-0-on-Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Huh, i just tried this and to me it works as it should, afaik. Enviroment is ubuntu 13.04 (with gcc 4.7.3).

If it still does not work for you, you might want to check out that the debug symbols are otherwise fine, with say gdb.

```
 % gcc test.c -g -o test
XXX@YYY
 % perf record ./test
[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.060 MB perf.data (~2620 samples) ]
XXX@YYY
 % perf report --stdio
# ========
# captured on: Wed Oct 16 11:58:40 2013
# hostname : sundberg-office-antec
# os release : 3.8.0-31-generic
# perf version : 3.8.13.8
# arch : x86_64
# nrcpus online : 2
# nrcpus avail : 2
# cpudesc : AMD Phenom(tm) II X2 555 Processor
# cpuid : AuthenticAMD,16,4,3
# total memory : 16434276 kB
# cmdline : /usr/bin/perf_3.8.0-31 record ./test 
# event : name = cycles, type = 0, config = 0x0, config1 = 0x0, config2 = 0x0, excl_usr = 0, excl_kern = 0, excl_host = 0, excl_guest = 1, precise_ip = 0, id = { 671, 672 }
# HEADER_CPU_TOPOLOGY info available, use -I to display
# HEADER_NUMA_TOPOLOGY info available, use -I to display
# pmu mappings: cpu = 4, software = 1, tracepoint = 2, ibs_fetch = 6, ibs_op = 7, breakpoint = 5
# ========
#
# Samples: 1K of event 'cycles'
# Event count (approx.): 1071717616
#
# Overhead  Command      Shared Object                     Symbol
# ........  .......  .................  .........................
#
    99.85%     test  test               [.] longa                
     0.08%     test  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] call_timer_fn        
     0.08%     test  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] task_work_run        
     0.00%     test  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] clear_page_c         
     0.00%     test  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] native_write_msr_safe


#
# (For a higher level overview, try: perf report --sort comm,dso)
#
```

Comment: thank you. May be,the reason is that I compile the kernel myself.If you use a perf on a typical kernel, the problem would not occur.