# Getting user-space stack information from perf

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, perf

I'm currently trying to track down some phantom I/O in a PostgreSQL build I'm testing. It's a multi-process server and it isn't simple to associate disk I/O back to a particular back-end and query.

I thought Linux's `perf` tool would be ideal for this, but I'm struggling to capture block I/O performance counter metrics and associate them with user-space activity.

It's easy to record block I/O requests and completions with, eg:

```
sudo perf record -g -T -u postgres -e 'block:block_rq_*'
```

and the user-space pid is recorded, but there's no kernel or user-space stack captured, or ability to snapshot bits of the user-space process's heap (say, query text) etc. So while you have the pid, you don't know what the process was doing at that point. Just `perf script` output like:

```
postgres  7462 [002] 301125.113632: block:block_rq_issue: 8,0 W 0 () 208078848 + 1024 [postgres]
```

If I add the `-g` flag to `perf record` it'll take snapshots of the *kernel* stack, but doesn't capture user-space state for perf events captured in the kernel. The user-space stack only goes up to the entry-point from userspace, like `LWLockRelease`, `LWLockAcquire`, `memcpy` (mmap'd IO), `__GI___libc_write`, etc.

So. Any tips? Being able to capture a snapshot of the *user-space* stack in response to *kernel* events would be ideal.

I'm on Fedora 19, 3.11.3-201.fc19.x86_64, Schrödinger’s Cat, with perf version 3.10.9-200.fc19.x86_64.

Comment: Returning to this, another possibility might be to use frace / systemtap / uprobes / ... instead. A talk at linux.conf.au 2014 suggested that systemtap may do this more easily at this point.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

OK, looks like there are several parts to this:

- I'm on x86_64, where most distros build with `-fomit-frame-pointer` by default, and `perf` can't follow the stack without frame pointers;
- .... unless it's a newer version built with `libunwind` support, in which case it supports `perf record -g dwarf`.

See:

- [the patch adding libunwind support to Perf](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1203.3/01569.html)
- [Debian bug 725075](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=725075).
- [linux perf: how to interpret and find hotspots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031210/linux-perf-how-to-interpret-and-find-hotspots)

I'm on Fedora 18, but [the same issue applies](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1025603). So if you're profiling code you're working on (as is likely on Stack Overflow), rebuild with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` and `-ggdb`.

I landed up rebuilding `perf` because I wanted to be able to compare to the stock RPMs:

- `sudo yum build-dep perf`
- `sudo yum install yum-utils rpmdevtools libunwind-devel`
- `yumdownloader --source perf` or download the appropriate `kernel-.....src.rpm` srpm
- `rpmdev-setuptree`
- `rpm -Uvh kernel-*.src.rpm`
- `cd $HOME/rpmbuild/SPECS`
- `rpmbuild -bp --target=$(uname -m) kernel.spec`

At this point you can just build a new `perf` if you want:

- `cd $HOME/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-*/linux-*/tools/perf`
- `make`

... which I did and tested that the updated `perf` does in fact capture a useful stack if built with libunwind available.

You can also build a new rpm:

- edit kernel.spec, uncomment the line `%define buildid ...`, change buildid to something like `.perfunwind`. Note it's `%define` not `% define`.
- In the same spec file, find:

  ```
  %global perf_make \
  make %{?_smp_mflags} -C tools/perf -s V=1 WERROR=0 NO_LIBUNWIND=1 HAVE_CPLUS_DEMANGLE=1 NO_GTK2=1 NO_LIBNUMA=1 NO_STRLCPY=1 prefix=%{_prefix}
  ```

  and delete `NO_LIBUNWIND=1`
- `rpmbuild -bb --without up --without mp --without pae --without debug --without doc --without headers --without debuginfo --without bootwrapper --without with_vdso_install --with perf kernel.spec` to produce new `perf` RPMs without building the whole kernel. Or if you want, omit the `--without` for the kernel flavour you want, in which case you'll also want to build headers, debuginfo, etc.
- `sudo rpm -Uvh $HOME/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/perf-*.fc19.x86_64.rpm`

See [the fedora project guide on building a custom kernel](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Building_a_custom_kernel).

I've reported the issue to Fedora; they shouldn't be using `NO_LIBUNWIND=1`. See [bug 1025603](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1025603).

Once you have a rebuilt `perf` you can use `perf record -g dwarf` to get full stacks.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter You might like the follow-up blog post then: http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/tracing-postgresql-perf/